# Perform multiple chi-squared test on dataframe based on column value

Tags: r, chi-squared, contingency

I have a data frame with count numbers and I want to perform a `chisq.test` for each value of the variable Cluster. So basically, I need 4 contingency tables (for "A","B","C","D") where rows = Category, columns = Drug, value = Total. And subsequently a `chisq.test` should be run for all 4 tabels.

Example data frame

```
df <- data.frame(Cluster = c(rep("A",8),rep("B",8),rep("C",8),rep("D",8)),
                 Category = rep(c(rep("0-1",2),rep("2-4",2),rep("5-12",2),rep(">12",2)),2),
                 Drug = rep(c("drug X","drug Y"),16),
                 Total = as.numeric(sample(20:200,32,replace=TRUE)))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, use `xtabs()` to produce stratified contingency tables.

```
tab <- xtabs(Total ~ Category + Drug + Cluster, df)
tab

# , , Cluster = A
# 
#         Drug
# Category drug X drug Y
#     >12      92     75
#     0-1      33    146
#     2-4     193     95
#     5-12     76    195
# 
# etc.
```

Then use `apply()` to conduct a Pearson's Chi-squared test over each stratum.

```
apply(tab, 3, chisq.test)

# $A
# 
#   Pearson's Chi-squared test
# 
# data:  array(newX[, i], d.call, dn.call)
# X-squared = 145.98, df = 3, p-value < 2.2e-16
#
# etc.
```

Furthermore, you can perform a Cochran-Mantel-Haenszel chi-squared test for ***conditional independence***.

```
mantelhaen.test(tab)

#   Cochran-Mantel-Haenszel test
# 
# data:  tab
# Cochran-Mantel-Haenszel M^2 = 59.587, df = 3, p-value = 7.204e-13
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I expected something a bit more complicated, but still, I never would have come to this solution on my own.